# Workaround to RAISERROR WITH NOWAIT buffering

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, raiserror

I'm using RAISERROR to produce progress output from stored procedures rather than using PRINT, to avoid PRINT's buffering of the output. Now I've discovered that RAISERROR will start buffering after 500 prints. Is there a way to get around this behavior ?
The Query below will show my point:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0

WHILE @i < 50000
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1 

    RAISERROR('%i prints', 0,1 , @i) with nowait;

    IF @i > 500  --<--after 500 prints RAISERROR starts buffering 50 prints before flushing.
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.050';
END;
```

Comment: Have you considered instrumenting the stored procedures with writes to a log table rather than relying on the client string output? If you need autonomous transaction support you can use a trick with loopback linked servers (http://www.dbbest.com/blog/autonomous-transactions-sql-server/)

Comment: I use scripts to backup and restore hundreds of databases, and would like the progress output printet rather than logged in a table, as the progress output from BACKUP and RESTORE is printet

Comment: @NWest You can use a `@table` variable, which is immune from transaction rollbacks, to not need all kinds of heinous workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Erland Sommerskand [reported](http://microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming.narkive.com/xN0lVjAP/flushing-print-output-to-the-query-window):

> However, beware that Mgmt Studio starts buffering also NOWAIT messages
>   after 500 messages.
>
> This does not happen with the old Query Analyzer that comes with SQL
>   2000

If you don't have QA available, perhaps you could try SQLCMD.EXE instead of SSMS. Maybe it will not do buffering after 500.

Comment: It's the same behavior with SQLCMD.EXE and I suppose I cannot use QA with SQL server 2008 ?!

Comment: @jhe sure, you can use Query Analyzer with SQL Server 2008, just don't try to do too much in addition to serving as a dumb query window. Enterprise Mangler will be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I remember trying this in LINQpad, linqpad can accept raw sql, and there was no buffer.

and I just tried i again and I can confirm it.

can you use linqpad?

Comment: Could be a solution, but as this often happens in production, we are not always allowed to install software.

Comment: @jhe, you don't have to install linqpad, you can download a zip file from linqpad website (standalone) and simply extract it and then run it, all this without install

Comment: Furthermore, you could put the LINQpad client on any developer machine that has a SQL connection; it doesn't have to be on the production server.